# skip first row in resultset to JTABLE display

Tags: java

i want to display data in jtable when i use dbutil it skips the first row and show the other rows here is the code:
i tried to make double loop with a rs.first() it didnt work

```
int id=0,quantite=0;
double prix=0.0;
ResultSet rs=null;
String sql = "Select id,prix,quantite from commande where quantite="+Integer.parseInt(tfRecherche.getText());
CommandeDao commande = new CommandeDao();
Statement st = commande.getSt();
try {
    rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        if(rs.isFirst()){
            System.out.println("first");
        }
        id= rs.getInt("id");
        quantite = rs.getInt("quantite");
        prix = rs.getDouble("prix");
        tbAffichage.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Also, please strive to post code that is well formatted. Your post had code with indentations all over the place and lots of excess unnecessary blank lines, making it difficult to read, and if folks can't read and understand your code, they won't be able to help you. I've tried to fix it, but in the future as the questioner this responsibility should be yours.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the while loop as with it you are re-setting the JTable's table model each time it iterates, deleting any information added in the previous iterations. Instead it seems to make more sense to simply use the ResultSet and `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel` to set the model once. Note that I've never used this utility, but it seems like it has to work this way. e.g.,

```
int id=0,quantite=0;
double prix=0.0;
ResultSet rs=null;
String sql = "Select id,prix,quantite from commande where quantite="+Integer.parseInt(tfRecherche.getText());
CommandeDao commande = new CommandeDao();
Statement st = commande.getSt();
try {
    rs= st.executeQuery(sql);

    // add this
    tbAffichage.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    // and get rid of this...
    // while(rs.next()){
        // ....
    // }

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    // close your connection here if not null, or use try-with resources
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`resultSetToTableModel(rs)` consumes all rows in your resultset. The problem is, that you already consumed the first row with the `rs.next()` call.

That is, why the row is missing in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked with the following code:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
res = pst.executeQuery();

if(res.isBeforeFirst())
{
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
}
```